How to debug composing draft messages
I'm trying to create a Google Workspace Addon for Gmail that reads the email and composes a draft.

I'm following the documentation https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/gmail/compose and I just copy/pasted the code from the example, here my code:
appsscript.json
{
  "timeZone": "Etc/GMT",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadata",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify"
  ],
  "gmail": {
    "name": "Test!",
    "logoUrl": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/receipt_black_24dp.png",
    "contextualTriggers": [
      {
        "unconditional": {},
        "onTriggerFunction": "getContextualAddOn"
      }
    ],
    "composeTrigger": {
      "selectActions": [
        {
          "text": "Generate answer",
          "runFunction": "createReplyDraft"
        }
      ],
      "draftAccess": "METADATA"
    },
    "primaryColor": "#41f470",
    "secondaryColor": "#94f441"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Gmail",
        "version": "v1",
        "serviceId": "gmail"
      }
    ]
  }
}

code:
/**
   *  Creates a draft email (with an attachment and inline image)
   *  as a reply to an existing message.
   *  @param {Object} e An event object passed by the action.
   *  @return {ComposeActionResponse}
   */
  function createReplyDraft(e) {
    // Activate temporary Gmail scopes, in this case to allow
    // a reply to be drafted.
    var accessToken = e.gmail.accessToken;
    GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);

    // Creates a draft reply.
    var messageId = e.gmail.messageId;
    var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
    var draft = message.createDraftReply('ciao');

    // Return a built draft response. This causes Gmail to present a
    // compose window to the user, pre-filled with the content specified
    // above.
    return CardService.newComposeActionResponseBuilder()
        .setGmailDraft(draft).build();
  }

The issue is that I'm getting this error: Invalid argument

this happens at this row:
var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);

I have the feeling that messageId is null, but I don't know how to debug it. In any case, since I simply copied the example from the documentation, I have no idea how to fix this, do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Unfortunately, the composeTrigger returns very little useful data, especially in comparison to the contextualTriggers. It does not return a messageId, as in messageId is not a property of the gmail object in this context (being that it is coming from the composeTrigger). That is the reason you are getting an error.
The only thing you can do is widen your authorization scopes to read all of a user's emails and search through the drafts for those that match the subject and recipients of the email being composed. Very inefficient, but that's the only option as of now.
It just goes to show how hypocritical Google is when it comes to privacy. Google could easily make the composeTrigger retrieve all the data on the email being composed that the contextualTriggers return for emails being read, but instead, despite years of requests from developers, Google has made it so a developer has no option other than to request the authority to read all emails. Then, Google puts the privacy control onus on external developers.

To learn to debug Google Apps Script code, please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting. There, you will learn the basics of debugging, logging, execution logs and the debugger.
The code in question is not "just a copy" of the code https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/gmail/compose, as it misses some parts and changes others, it's not coherent with the written instructions. More specifically, the manifest includes composeTrigger to call createReplyDraft, but this function should be called by a Google Apps Script action. That might be used when an existing draft is edited to create a new draft as intended. The code in the referred article includes de following, which is not included in the question body:
var composeAction = CardService.newAction()
    .setFunctionName('createReplyDraft');
var composeButton = CardService.newTextButton()
    .setText('Compose Reply')
    .setComposeAction(
        composeAction,
        CardService.ComposedEmailType.REPLY_AS_DRAFT);

Resources

Build a Google Workspace Add-on with Apps Script

Related

How to debug Google Apps Script (aka where does Logger.log log to?)
How to get debugging information for Apps Scripts functions called from a sheet?


Hi, unfortunately my question was not about debugging as you edited it. Learning how to debug it it's a plus but not the reason I asked the question. In any case, I know how to log, but I can't understand how to read the logs when the code is fired from the gmail UI. Having said that, I'd like to understand how to make the example code work. I know it's not just a copy past since the example was not complete, do you knwo how to complete it? I don't know where to put that code and how to call it. Thanks

Regarding how to find the logs, see my answer to How to get debugging information for Apps Scripts functions called from a sheet?. It has snaptshots.

Regarding how to complete the code, I added a link to my answer. It's a quickstart. You might exclude the Calendar and Drive parts to focus only on the Gmail part. Please ensure to understand this part before going into the code required to create a reply draft. If you have questions about that, please post them as new questions.
